# How to include queues into CRM solution?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to export customizations from my crm instance. I created some new queues and I want to include them into solution. Is that possible? And how?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, queues cannot be included within a solution. You'll have to import them or create them in some manner after your solution imports.